# Query to find extract time between

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Im a beginner with SQL and need help to get some transactions in our WMS between 00.00.00 and 06.00.00 but can't make it work.

This is how far I have come,

```
SELECT cast(datreg as time) [time], logguser, l16lcode, partno, l16qty, datreg
FROM L16T3
WHERE datreg > '0000-00-00 00:00:00' 
AND datreg < '9999-99-99 06:00:00'
AND L16T3.l16lcode = 2
```

I dont know what to write to get transactions only between 24.00-06.00

(Using SQL Server 2012)

Best Regards

Comment: Hint: Consider converting your data to a `time` first. The second date you have there isn't valid, though, as there's are not 99 days or 99 months in any calendar.

Comment: Or extract the hour from datereg and check whether it's between 0 and 5. Here is the documentation on date and time functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks for the tips! This site is great, fast answers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this condition:

```
WHERE DATEPART(hour, datreg) BETWEEN 0 AND 5 OR
(DATEPART(hour, datreg) = 6 AND DATEPART(minute, datreg) = 0 AND DATEPART(second, datreg) = 0)
```

Comment: I don't think it'll be necessary to include the fraction of a millisecond at exactly 6:00h. `WHERE DATEPART(hour, datreg) BETWEEN 0 AND 5` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Thorsten and thank you for formatting dns_nx!

Comment: OMG! its working you are awesome. Now I will study how you did this! Thanks alot! I only have one problem now. The l16lcode gives me all kind of transactions instead of only the code 2. Why is that?

Comment: On a side note: While `AND` does have precedence over `OR`, I'd still always use parentheses when mixing the two: `WHERE ... OR (... AND ... AND ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
SELECT cast(datreg as time) as [time], logguser, l16lcode, partno, l16qty, datreg
FROM L16T3 l
WHERE CONVERT(time, l.datreg) >= '00:00:00' AND
      CONVERT(time, l.datreg) < '06:00:00' AND
      l.l16lcode = 2;
```

You can also use the hours:

```
WHERE DATEPART(hour, l.datreg) >= 0 AND
      DATEPART(hour, l.datreg) < 6 AND
      l.l16lcode = 2;
```

However, this does not generalize so easily if, say, the second time were `06:30:00`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked perfectly, it seems like there is alot of different ways to code in SQL and get same results!

Answer (score 0):

Something lie this perhaps:

```
SELECT IIF(CONVERT(TIME, GETDATE()) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '23:59:59','TRUE','FALSE');
```

Try the above query in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/97428)

In your case it would be something like this:

```
SELECT cast(datreg as time) [time], logguser, l16lcode, partno, l16qty, datreg
FROM L16T3
WHERE CONVERT(TIME, datreg ) BETWEEN '00:00:00' AND '06:00:00'
AND L16T3.l16lcode = 2
```